# Musicg library not working for mp3 , rm , wma

Tags: java, android, mp3, wav, musicg

I am trying to build song matching app . The android app would read music files and generate a fingerprint and send this to server. Server wil verify the fingerprint against its database of fingerprints to get highest matched similiarity.

For this I was looking into musicg , I am able to use it for .wav songs, but any other formatted is not supported.

How do I support musicg for non-wav formats like mp3, wma, rm etc..?

Using ffmpeg to convert to wav and then processing using musicg is an option.

Are there any other options in your mind?

Answer (score 0):

There is other options like:

- [Superpowered](https://www.google.com/amp/s/superpowered.com/superpowered-android-audio-engine-amp)
- [TarsosDSP](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP&ved=2ahUKEwirm_jMha3iAhWh1uAKHS2pB_cQFjAEegQIBxAC&usg=AOvVaw35rGGWNfjJlaaxnfRDvQQ1&cshid=1558456356291)
- [Oboe](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/google/oboe&ved=2ahUKEwimjPC4ha3iAhVCA2MBHXx_DgMQFjABegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw3CvXiz8XQOXO-MhwLkJxyZ&cshid=1558456402685)

But, for what you are trying to do, I would suggest you stick with ffmpeg because there is already libraries that has build it for Android.